# Datetime strptime in python

Tags: python, datetime

I've tried the following code :

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.strptime("01/27/2012", "%m/%d/%Y")
print(d)
```

and the output is :

```
2012-01-27 00:00:00
```

I'am using Linux Mint :

```
test@testsrv ~/pythonvault $ date
Fri Jun 16 21:40:57 EEST 2017
```

So,the question is why the output of python code returns a date in `"%Y/%m/%d" ( 2012-01-27 )` instead of `"%m/%d/%Y"` format ?

Please note that I'am using python 2.7

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat

Comment: because it's the default representation. You specified ``"%m/%d/%Y"`` only for parsing, not for printing. To format a datetime, use ``strftime``.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to make sure you provide input accordingly

```
datetime.strptime(date_string,date_string_format).strftime(convert_to_date_string_format)
```

To print the date in specified format you need to provide format as below.

```
import datetime
d =datetime.datetime.strptime("01/27/2012","%m/%d/%Y").strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
print d
```

**Output:**

```
01/27/2012
```

**[>>Demo<<](https://ideone.com/tFcKUn)**

Comment: How do I get "now" as the required input format? This is a chicken and egg problem...

Answer (score 5):

`datetime.strptime(date_string, format)` function returns a `datetime` object corresponding to `date_string`, parsed according to `format`. 
When you print `datetime` object, it is formatted as a string in ISO 8601 format, `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS`

References:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat

Comment: It's quite clear now, thanks all of you for the instant answers!

Answer (score 3):

As astutely noted in the comments, you are parsing to a datetime object using the format you specified.

[`strptime(...)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) is **Str**ing **P**arse **Time**. You have specified the format for how the string should be interpreted to initialize a Datetime object, but that format is only utilized for initialization. By default, when you go to print that datetime object, you are getting the representation of `str(DatetimeObjectInstance)` (*in your case, `str(d)`*).

If you want a different format, you should use **Str**ing **F**ormat **Time** ([`strftime(...)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime))

Answer (score 2):

```
import datetime

str_time= "2018-06-03 08:00:00"
date_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(str_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print date_date
```

Comment: It's good practice on StackOverflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between `datetime.strp[arse]time()` and `datetime.strf[ormat]time()`.

The first one, `strptime()` allows you to create a date object from a string source, provided you can tell it what format to expect:

```py
strDate = "11-Apr-2019_09:15:42"
dateObj = datetime.strptime(strDate, "%d-%b-%Y_%H:%M%S")

print(dateObj)  # shows: 2019-04-11 09:15:42
```

The second one, `strftime()` allows you to export your date object to a string in the format of your choosing:

```py
dateObj = datetime(2019, 4, 11, 9, 19, 25)
strDate = dateObj.strftime("%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")

print(strDate)  # shows: 04/11/19 09:19:25
```

What you're seeing is simply the default string format of a datetime object because you didn't explicitly tell it what format to use.

Checkout http://strftime.org/ for a list of all the different string format options that are availble.

Comment: Late to the party I know, but (IMHO) none of the answers really explained *why* he's seeing the different format from is input.

Answer (score 1):

> The datetime.strptime() class method creates a datetime object from a
> string representing a date and time and a corresponding format string.

- %a

  ```
  Weekday as locale’s abbreviated name.

  Sun, Mon, …, Sat (en_US);
  So, Mo, …, Sa (de_DE)
  ```
- %A

  ```
  Weekday as locale’s full name.

  Sunday, Monday, …, Saturday (en_US);
  Sonntag, Montag, …, Samstag (de_DE)
  ```
- %w

  ```
  Weekday as a decimal number, where 0 is Sunday and 6 is Saturday.

  0, 1, …, 6
  ```
- %d

  ```
  Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number.

  01, 02, …, 31
  ```
- %b

  ```
  Month as locale’s abbreviated name.

  Jan, Feb, …, Dec (en_US);
  Jan, Feb, …, Dez (de_DE)
  ```
- %B

  ```
   Month as locale’s full name.

   January, February, …, December (en_US);
   Januar, Februar, …, Dezember (de_DE)
  ```
- %m

  ```
  Month as a zero-padded decimal number.

  01, 02, …, 12
  ```
- %y

  ```
  Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number.

  00, 01, …, 99
  ```
- %Y

  ```
  Year with century as a decimal number.

  0001, 0002, …, 2013, 2014, …, 9998, 9999
  ```
- %H

  ```
  Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.

  00, 01, …, 23
  ```
- %I

  ```
  Hour (12-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.

  01, 02, …, 12
  ```
- %p

  ```
  Locale’s equivalent of either AM or PM.

  AM, PM (en_US);
  am, pm (de_DE)
  ```
- %M

  ```
  Minute as a zero-padded decimal number.

  00, 01, …, 59
  ```
- %S

  ```
  Second as a zero-padded decimal number.

  00, 01, …, 59
  ```
- %f

  ```
  Microsecond as a decimal number, zero-padded to 6 digits.

  000000, 000001, …, 999999
  ```
- %z

  ```
  UTC offset in the form ±HHMM[SS[.ffffff]] (empty string if the object is naive).

  (empty), +0000, -0400, +1030, +063415, -030712.345216
  ```
- %Z

  ```
  Time zone name (empty string if the object is naive).

  (empty), UTC, GMT
  ```
- %j

  ```
  Day of the year as a zero-padded decimal number.

  001, 002, …, 366
  ```
- %U

  ```
  Week number of the year (Sunday as the first day of the week) as a zero-padded decimal number. All days in a new year preceding the
  ```

  first Sunday are considered to be in week 0.

  ```
  00, 01, …, 53
  ```
- %W

  ```
  Week number of the year (Monday as the first day of the week) as a zero-padded decimal number. All days in a new year preceding the
  ```

  first Monday are considered to be in week 0.

  ```
  00, 01, …, 53
  ```
- %c

  ```
  Locale’s appropriate date and time representation.

  Tue Aug 16 21:30:00 1988 (en_US);
  Di 16 Aug 21:30:00 1988 (de_DE)
  ```
- %x

  ```
  Locale’s appropriate date representation.

  08/16/88 (None);
  08/16/1988 (en_US);
  16.08.1988 (de_DE)
  ```
- %X

  ```
  Locale’s appropriate time representation.

  21:30:00 (en_US);
  21:30:00 (de_DE)
  ```
- %%

  ```
  A literal '%' character.

  %
  ```

for more information please visit [official](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) website for python

### Example Programs for better understanding

***Program 1:***

```
from datetime import datetime

data = "2022-02-09 12:25:22"

dat = datetime.strptime(data, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print(dat)
```

***Output:***

```
2022-02-09 12:25:22
```

***Program 2:***

```
from datetime import datetime
data = "Thursday, 10 February 2022 11:28:45 am"
dat = datetime.strptime(data, "%A, %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S %p")
print(dat)
```

***Output:***

```
2022-02-10 11:28:45
```