# dateutil parse - OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Tags: python

I'm trying to parse a Unix date like -
20220424141334.3717010 like this -

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
ud: str = "20220414223231.1489431"
fs: str = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%f0"
p = parse(ud)   <- Error here
f = p.strftime(fs)
```

but I'm getting

```
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

I tried to look online but I found nothing

How can I parse it?

Thanks

EDIT -

This is the definition of the time [image]

The goal is to format it but the error is while parsing.
I need to be dynamic and except as many str date types as possible

Comment: Try [datetime.datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime)
The error is because your input looks like a number, so parser attempts to parse as time passed since 1970-01-01

Comment: this is not a unix timestamp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Datetime strptime in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44596077/datetime-strptime-in-python)

Comment: @DannyVarod how can I make it understand the format? and make it dynamic at the same time..?

Comment: @eshirvana it is an ABAP timestamp. thanks for the correction. about the link - it doesn't answering my question, but thanks for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all.

In the end, I used a regex to fetch part of the date.

```
REG_W_DOT = r'\d{14}\.\d{6}'
REG_WO_DOT = r'\d{20}'

# This will check if we have the format
regexed = re.search(REG_W_DOT, date_string) or re.search(REG_WO_DOT, date_string)
if regexed:
    date_string = regexed.group()
converted_datetime = datetime.strptime(date_string, format)
```

This way I can verify the length of the date and in case it's what I want - I'll parse it.

Answer (score 2):

Your value has 7 digits for the fractional seconds. The %f format specification only handles 6 digits. Therefore you could do this:

```
from datetime import datetime

ud = "20220414223231.1489431"
datetime.strptime(ud[:-1], '%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%f')
```

...but, depending on your exact requirements this may not be accurate enough

Comment: thanks. 1. I add an extra "0" in the format for this purpose (7 instead of 6). 2. I want it to be dynamic so I won't depend on the str date coming. what can I do?

Comment: The added 0 is meaningless in the context of the format specifier. However, if the factional part is fewer that 6 characters then my proposal will not work. What you have to think about first of all is whether the least significant part of the fraction is important to you. If there are fewer than 6 parts to the fraction then you could just pad with zeroes. IF ABAP TIMESTAMPL **always** has 7 decimal parts then just truncate as per my answer

Comment: I just checked. TIMESTAMPL **always** has 7 decimal parts (including trailing zeroes) so, as I said, just truncate

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used this idea and created a regex truncate just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 1):

If you give `dateutil.parser.parse()` a little more to go on, it will do what you want.

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> ud = "2022-04-14 22:32:31.1489431"
>>> parse(ud)
datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 14, 22, 32, 31, 148943)
```

Even if you are getting a string with no punctuation, there is nothing to stop you adding it. This will give you the same result:

```
>>> ud = "20220414223231.1489431"
>>> ud2 = ud[:4],ud[4:6],ud[6:8],ud[8:10],ud[10:12],ud[12:]
>>> parse("{}-{}-{} {}:{}:{}".format(*ud2))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! interesting. The thing is, that I'm getting the str from out of my system so I can't control the format of the input. is there a way to work with the ABAP format I mentioned in the EDIT?